# создание чата на node.js на хостинге

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, node.js

на хостинге установили node открыли порт 3000 порт прослушивается, при обращении lptf.it:3000 или http://185.53.160.215:3000/ выводится сообщение Hello Node.js Server!. Казалось бы все хорошо! но! я хочу дальше создание чата, и в корне сайта создаю файлик (сервер) с кодом (пример с интернета, я новичОк):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('host', process.env.HOST || 'localhost');

var logger = require('log4js').getLogger();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 3000;


 app.use(express.static('/home/urlyogyj/public_html/views/chat.php'));
app.get('/chat.php', function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/home/urlyogyj/public_html/views/chat.php');
});

app.use('/fonts', express.static('/home/urlyogyj/node_modules/uikit/src/fonts/'));

 app.get('/socket.io.js', function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/home/urlyogyj/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');
});

app.get('/jquery.js', function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/home/urlyogyj/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
 });

 app.get('/uikit.js', function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/home/urlyogyj/node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js');
});

app.get('/uikit.css', function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/home/urlyogyj/node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.almost-flat.min.css');
});

app.get('/animate.css', function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/home/urlyogyj/node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css');
});

function usersCountToLog(){
logger.info('User count: '+io.engine.clientsCount);
 }

 io.on('connection', function(socket){

function setName(name){
    if(name != undefined && name != ''){
        socket.session = {};
        socket.session.userName = name;
        socket.session.address = socket.handshake.address; 
        socket.session.id = socket.id;          

        socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', socket.session);
        socket.emit('userName', socket.session);


        socket.emit('userList', io.length);

        logger.info('User '+socket.session.userName+' join from IP: '+socket.session.address);
        usersCountToLog();
        var clients = io.sockets.connected;


        var clientsList = {}
        for(var key in clients){
            if(clients[key].session)
                clientsList[key] = clients[key].session;
        }

        socket.emit('clientsList', clientsList);
        console.log(clientsList);
    }
    else
        socket.emit('setName');
}
setName(null);
socket.on('setName', function(name){
    if(name.length > 0)
        setName(name);
    else
        socket.emit('setName');
});

socket.on('message', function(msg){
    if(socket.session){
        if(socket.session.userName === null || socket.session.userName == '' || socket.session.userName == undefined){
            socket.emit('setName');
        }else{
            logger.trace('-----------');
            logger.trace('User: ' + socket.session.userName + ' |  
Message: ' + msg);
            logger.trace('====> Sending message to other chaters...');

            socket.broadcast.emit('messageFromClients', msg,  
socket.session.userName);
            socket.emit('messageToClients', msg,      
socket.session.userName);
        }
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    if(socket.session){
        io.sockets.emit('userDisconnected', socket.session);
        logger.info('User '+socket.session.userName+' left chat');
        usersCountToLog();
    }
});
});

console.log('server started, tipa...');
```

как видно по коду прописал адреса к файлам, они верные, в консоле перезапускаю сервер командой

```
node /home/urlyogyj/public_html/app.js screen
```

после этого обновляю адрес lptf.it:3000 и все равно без перемен, выводит Hello Node.js Server!
я не понимаю почему, и где и как можно отслеживать ошибки.
чего вообще хочу добиться:
до авторизации какого-либо пользователя чат не нужен, как только пользователь авторизовывается на сайте, открывается сокет и на сайте для всех остальных пользователей и гостей видна надпись что тот авторизованный пользователь в сети, и напротив его логина появляется кнопка создать чат, но только для авторизованых пользователей, при нажатии на нее открывается окошко чата, как на сайте вконтакте или фейсбуке, у получателя сообщения есть блок со списком все кто прислал ему сообщение, получатель нажимает на автора и пользователи начинают общение, каждый диалог с новым пользователь должен запускать свое окошко чата. причем этот чат существует на всех страницах сайта. после выхода пользователя через кнопку выход или закрытии вкладки сокет закрывается, а все сообщения записываются в базу данных!

Comment: копайте в сторону `webSocket`, Модуль `ws`

Comment: можно как-то подробнее?

Comment: Вот [сдесь](https://socket.io/demos/chat/) почти все, что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Чат на `webSoket`. Для работы необходимо установить модуль `ws`

`html`:

```
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="chatInput">
    <button id="send" type="button">Отправить</button>
    <script>
        let chatInput = document.getElementById("chatInput");
let send = document.getElementById("send");
let body = document.querySelector("body");

send.addEventListener("click", sendChatMessage)
ws  = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3333");
ws.addEventListener("message", checkChatMessage);

function sendChatMessage(event){
    var textMessage = chatInput.value;
    ws.send(textMessage);
    chatInput.value = "";
}

function checkChatMessage(event){
    var data = event.data;
    showChatMessage(data)
}

function showChatMessage(data){
    let tegP = document.createElement("p");
    tegP.innerText = data;
    body.appendChild(tegP)
}

    </script>
    </body>
```

`server.js`

```
const webSocket = require("ws");
const wsPort = 3333;
var playerOnline = {};

var wsServer = new webSocket.Server({
    port: wsPort
}, ()=>{
    console.log("**************Сервер Websocket запущен на порту:", wsPort, "**************")
});

wsServer.on("connection", (ws, req)=>{
    var id = Math.random();
    playerOnline[id] = ws;
    console.log("новое соединение " + id);

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    // console.log('получено сообщение ' + message);
    for (var key in playerOnline) {
      playerOnline[key].send(message);
    }
  });

    ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('соединение закрыто ' + id);
    delete playerOnline[id];
  });

});

//эта часть кода отвечает за первоначальное подключение
const fs = require("fs"),
    http = require ("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    index = fs.readFileSync('./index.html'),//здесь нужно прописать путь к своему html
    port = 3000,
    server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Сервер запущен по адресу localhost:"+port);
  console.log("*****************************************************************");
})

server.on("request", function(req, res){
  if (req.method == "GET") {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index)
  } 
})
```

;

Comment: я установил модуль ws и запустил server в консоле вышла ошибка Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1366:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1407:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1495:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/urlyogyj/public_html/app.js:38:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)

Comment: @vkt, _EADDRINUSE_ говорит о том, что данный адрес занят.

Comment: каким образом занят? мне хостер открыл порт 3000

Comment: Укажите другой порт в переменной "port" или остановите приложение, которое сейчас занимает порт 3000